# Не работает кнопка "В корзину", после нажатия на кнопку "Продолжить покупки"

Tags: javascript

Есть сайт на Тильде: https://geo-food.com/

Когда добавляем товар в корзину, содержимое корзины вызывается автоматически.
Если жмем из корзины "Продолжить покупки", попадаем на главную, но больше ничего добавить не можем.

Код кнопки "Продолжить покупки"

```
<script>
$( document ).ready(function() {
  $('.t706__sidebar-bottom').prepend("<button class='continue-btn'>ПРОДОЛЖИТЬ ПОКУПКИ</button>");
  $('.continue-btn').on('click touchend', function(){
    $('#rec529850416').hide();
    
    $('body').removeClass('t706__body_cartsidebarshowed');
  });
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$('#rec529850416').hide();` - выполняя этот код, вы делаете `display: none` этому блоку. В то время как появление и скрытие блока с корзиной выполнено по другой логике. Попробуйте использовать уже созданную функцию в Тильде. `tcart__closeCartSidebar();` Возможно так:

```
<script>
$( document ).ready(function() {
  $('.t706__sidebar-bottom').prepend("<button class='continue-btn'>ПРОДОЛЖИТЬ ПОКУПКИ</button>");
  $('.continue-btn').on('click touchend', function(){
    window.tcart__closeCartSidebar();
  });
});
</script>
```

Откуда я узнал о ней? На неё можно выйти, если просмотреть какие прослушиватели есть на кнопке закрытия корзины.

Comment: Спасибо огромное)

Comment: @Ирина Тарусова Благодарен за благодарность :) Однако лучше всего будет отметить ответ как решение, если оно действительно помогло вам, либо проголосовать за него. Это будет в согласии с правилами на этом ресурсе https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers